# Hide rows based on criteria excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, hide

I have a small Excel Macro that goes through a large list of names and sees if it is in a smaller list and if it is, it hides the entire row.  It doesn't throw any errors but for some reason it just doesn't hide anything and I am very confused why.  Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub Filter()

Dim i As Long, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, j As Long

Set rng1 = Sheet6.Range("H2:H3")
Set rng2 = Sheet5.Range(Range("K2"), Sheet5.Range("K2").End(xlDown))

For i = 1 To rng2.Rows.Count

    For j = 1 To rng1.Rows.Count

        If rng2.Cells(i, 11).Value = rng1.Cells(j, 7).Value Then
            rng2.Cells(i, 11).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If

    Next j

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Well just going to point out that the `j` loop will only and always execute once since `Range("H2:H3").Count = 2`

Comment: Whoops, my mistake. I changed that and now it says the range method fails on the line: `Set rng2 = Sheet5.Range(Range("K2"), Range("K2").End(xlDown))`

Comment: Well changing what you changed has 0 effect on that line...

Comment: I know that. But why would it fail now and not before? I am unsure what would cause this...

Comment: You asked pretty much the same question before, received some answers, didn't comment why you do not like them. Now you post some code full of bugs (Range without parent object, wrong subscripts). So the question is: what exactly do you  expect?

Comment: I am just seeking help as to why my code is not working.  I fixed the issue with the parent object but it still doesn't hide any rows.  I am unsure what the issue would be here...

Comment: 'rng2.Cells(i, 11)' - this one and similar are incorrect - rng1 and rng2 have only 1 column, so the second subscript should be 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Set rng2 = Sheet5.Range("K2:" & Sheet5.Range("K2").End(xlDown).AddressLocal)
```

Answer (score 0):

As user3964076 suggests in the comments, the issue is that a reference like Range("H2:H3").cells(2,11) will not return the value in the second row of the eleventh column of your sheet, but rather the value in the third row of the eighteenth column. The code is treating H2 as the first cell in a range, and then moving over an additional 1 row and 10 columns from there.

Try this instead:

```
Sub Filter()
  Dim i As Long, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, j As Long
  Set rng1 = Sheet6.Range("H2:H3")
  Set rng2 = Sheet5.Range(Range("K2"), Sheet5.Range("K2").End(xlDown))
  For i = 1 To rng2.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To rng1.Rows.Count
      If rng2.Cells(i, 1).Value = rng1.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
        rng2.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
      End If
     Next j
  Next i
End Sub
```